# Vimeo - Embed not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, embed, vimeo

I've developed a page for a client and something really weird is happening:
http://cpdlectures.com/IStructE/Default.aspx

This Vimeo video works inside of Chrome, Mozilla etc. But it doesn't work in IE.

I initially thought it might be scripting error or something, so:

1. I hit F12 to open my developer tools,
2. Click Script,
3. Refresh page to watch the JS code execution,
4. Video works!

close Developer tools, video still works after refresh. Close the browser, reopen, broken again, refresh without opening developer tools, still broken.

What? Are Microsoft implementing the Observer effect into their browsers now?

How can this be?

Comment: For what it's worth, I am having the same problem and can also reproduce it on the site you linked. It's intermittent, and seems to happen more when I click play very soon after the page loads. This is with IE9.

Comment: @smithy thanks the issue is solved now

Comment: This problem was actually caused by Vimeo updating their code base and made a bad publish. See what happens is when you open IE developer tools IE will then create an instance of JavaScript's `console` until then the application will crash where ever you use `console.log` video didn't remove these calls or whatever...

Comment: seems like an old issue they just don't care about: https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:68905

Comment: @vsync My issue was solved a couple of days after I first had this problem. It's a problem with calling Console.Log in JS in IE as far as I was aware, perhaps they carelessly keep leaving their logging in their production code... either way looks like they don't care too much by your link. Youtube for the win!

Comment: how could you fix it if their code is encapsulated within an iframe you have no access to?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem was updating the Flash!

See the print with Vimeo above and Youtube below (WinXP - IE8). Before and after upload.

## Before:

[image: Before Upload]

## After:

[image: After Upload]

Comment: Same here! Just remember to restart the machine after updating flash.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the link you provided in IE9 and the video played fine. I then changed the Browser Mode in the IE Toolbar to render in IE8 and IE7 and the video played correctly in both those browser modes. I think you may have a cached version of the website and suggest clearing your IE browser cache.

Tools > Internet Options > General Tab > Browsing History > Delete... > Make sure "Temporary Internet Files" is selected.

If that doesnt work could you let us know what version of IE you are using and perhaps provide a sample of your code?

Comment: thanks crazymatt the problem has been solved their is some issue in my server path that's why the code is not running on my site.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement, and I'm using the Froogaloop to add the event ready handler to the Vimeo iframe.

The video is initially hidden, but plays when user clicks on the play button on a custom splash screen.

The problem only occurred in IE (tried 8 - 10). Other browsers worked perfectly.

Turns out IF the video is not initially hidden (display none), there is no issue.

As a quick fix, I've offset the video from the screen. Upon window ready, I move the video back into view while hiding it simultaneously. This fixed the player ready event not firing in IE, using Froogaloop.

Comment: IE has all sorts of problems like this. It's super annoying when all the other browsers say "Yes!" and IE says no. Just a quick tip, make sure safari on the iPad/iPhone doesn't zoom out 5000% to include the offset video visually :)